# IIS throws 500.0 error when serving files

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an asp.net mvc / angular web app which has been working fine for years.  Its just been moved to a new server (Windows 2019, IIS7) and now is throwing many console errors and server errors, eg

DashBoard:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://MyServer/SiteName/Content/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Also many 500 errors, even when loading a gif file.  The files are all where they should be, I have unblocked them in windows file explorer, the user account running the application pool has full access to the files and is an admin on the IIS server.  Authentication mode is windows.  I am really out of ideas as to what could be the issue.  Most files are served ok (razor views, bundles).  I read something about TLS versions but am reluctant to add registry keys as its a clients server.  I have a feeling its some fundamental issue with IIS configuration.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How did you move it? Syncing IIS servers with Web Deployment Tool?

Comment: Manually copied files

Comment: I added request tracing and got this :
ModuleName
IIS Web Core 

Notification
AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST 

HttpStatus
500 

HttpReason
Internal Server Error 

HttpSubStatus
0 

ErrorCode
Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.
 (0x80070542)

Comment: I wonder why you chose to manually copy, but in that way you missed all relevant settings and permissions. I suggest you hire an experienced consultant to guide your migration, instead of asking around. Without touching the servers and your web app, it is impossible for anyone here to give proper advice.

Comment: Thanks for your sage advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set load user profile = true in the application pool first, if this alone doesn't work, log onto the iis server as the app pool user.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by logging onto the IIS server once as the Application Pool user (a non-local service account in this case).  This caused the profile of that user to be created locally which must be required by IIS for authentication purposes.

Comment: That unfortunately shows unfamiliarity of IIS settings. The actual solution is to set `loadUserProfile` to true, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel#configuration. If you use a migration tool like Web Deployment Tool, or hire a consultant, this can be figured out within just a few minutes during migration. But you can easily miss such when merely copying the files over.

Comment: Thanks for all your assistance, its really been invaluable.